# MVC: Connect class to results of database function/stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, data-binding, sql-function

How can I execute a SQL function in MVC?

I am trying to link the results of a table returning function to a class I defined. I have set up the connection string and created the database context with `public DbSet<Classname> variable{get; set;}` how can i link this to the results of a function

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Entity Framework? Here is an article you can read:

http://rationalgeek.com/blog/function-imports/